# Winston File transport logs escape characters

Tags: logging, sails.js, winston

I am using winston to log in a Sails app. This is my configuration:

```
var customLogger = new winston.Logger({
    transports: [
        new(winston.transports.File)({
            level: 'debug',
            filename: 'app.log',
            colorize: false,
            showLevel: false,
            prettyPrint: false,
            exitOnError: false,
            json: true,
            zippedArchive: true,
            maxsize: 1000000000,
            maxFiles: 30,
            tailable: true
        }),
        new(winston.transports.Console)({
            level: 'info',
            exitOnError: false,
            colorize: false,
            showLevel: false
        })
    ],
});
```

But in the output file there are odd characters.

```
{"level":"info","message":"\u001b[32minfo: \u001b[39m","timestamp":"2016-05-12T17:58:03.281Z"}
```

Comment: those are colors from console.

Comment: yes, but I wan't to avoid output those characters.

Comment: Followed the guidelines in this blog and it worked - https://thisdavej.com/using-winston-a-versatile-logging-library-for-node-js/

Answer (score 2):

I did face a similar issue and resolved it by removing **winston.format.colorize()** statement from the below code to get rid of the odd or escape codes as part of the log file.

```
const logFormat = winston.format.combine (
winston.format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS' }),
winston.format.colorize(),
winston.format.align(),
winston.format.printf(
    info => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level.toUpperCase()}: ${info.message}`    
));
```

While below shared is the complete working code without any issues associated with odd or escape codes.

Default configurations captured as part of **/zipCode/config/default.json** file

```
{
   "port":      3000,
   "logConfig": {
        "logFolder":    ".//logs//",
        "logFile":      "zip-code-%DATE%.log",
        "logLevel":     "info"
    }
}
```

Incorporating the create logger implementation as part of **/zipCode/logger/log.js** file

```
/**
 * @author: dinesh.lomte
 */
const winston = require('winston');
const dailyRotateFile = require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
const config = require('config');
const logFormat = winston.format.combine (
    winston.format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS' }),
    winston.format.align(),
    winston.format.printf(
        info => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level.toUpperCase()}: ${info.message}`    
    )
);
const transport = new dailyRotateFile({
    filename:       config.get('logConfig.logFolder') + config.get('logConfig.logFile'),
    datePattern:    'YYYY-MM-DD',
    zippedArchive:  true,
    maxSize:        '20m',
    maxFiles:       '14d',
    level:          config.get('logConfig.logLevel')        
});

transport.on('rotate', function(oldFile, newFile) {
    // Call function like upload to s3 or on cloud
});

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    format:     logFormat,
    transports: [
        transport,
        new winston.transports.Console({
            level:  config.get('logConfig.logLevel')
        })
    ]
});

module.exports = logger;
```

Below **/zipCode/api/controller.js** file showing the logger usage

```
/**
 * @author: dinesh.lomte
 */
'use strict';

var distance = require('../service/distance');
var logger = require('../logger/log');

var controllers = {
    get_distance: function(req, res) {
        logger.info('Processing get_distance request...');
        distance.find(req, res, function(err, dist) {
            if (err) {
                logger.error('Failed to process distance request, due to: ' + err);
                res.send(err);
            }
            logger.debug('Processed get_distance request...');
            res.json(dist);
        });
    }
};

module.exports = controllers;
```

Answer (score 0):

I put a toggle switch on [winston's](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/tree/2.x) coloring feature depending on whether it's enabled via `dotenv` library:

**.env:**

```
LOG_COLORIZE_FORMAT_ENABLED=false
```

**Logger.ts**

```
require('dotenv').config()
 ...

   const formats = [
      format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss:ms' }),
      process.env.LOG_COLORIZE_FORMAT_ENABLED === 'true' ? format.colorize({ all: true }) : null,
      format.splat(),
      format.printf(info => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`),
      
    ].filter(f => f !== null);
    
    const _format = formats.length ? format.combine(...formats) : null;
    
    const Logger = createLogger({
      level: level(),
      levels,
      format: _format,
      transports: [new transports.Console()],
    });
    
    export { Logger };
```

Answer (score -1):

Currently in sails you don't need to use `customLogger` to use Winston. You can install [sails-hook-winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-winston). Than your `config/log.js` will look like that:

```js
var path = require('path');
var pkgJSON = require(path.resolve('package.json'));

module.exports.log = {

    // This options are for Console transport that is used by default
    level: 'info', // you are familiar with this value, right?
    timestamp: true, // if you want to output the timestamp in the console transport
    colors: false,
    // Transports
    // more information: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md
    transports: [{
        module: require('winston-daily-rotate-file'),
        config: {
            dirname: path.resolve('logs'),
            datePattern: '.yyyy-MM-dd.log',
            filename: pkgJSON.name,
            prettyPrint: true,
            timestamp: true,
            level: 'info',
            json: true,
            colors: false
        }
    }]
};
```

You can use few [transports](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md) in same time with different log level.